# Why Jest (JavaScript framework for unit testing) does not work with `this`?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, jestjs

```
class Test {
  static Test1 () { console.log(this); this.Test2();  }
  static Test2 () { console.log('qwe'); }
}

Test.Test1();

export default Test;
export const Test1 = Test.Test1;
```

Compiled with BabelJS with ES2015 preset. With `node` the compiled code runs fine. But within unit test `this` is `undefined`. Why this happens?

Comment: I tested here and it seems to work https://repl.it/repls/LumpyJadedIggypops, it looks like there might a problem with how jest transpile your code

Comment: Your example has no class and `this`?

Comment: The sharing function doesn't seem to work. If you replace the code with yours, it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I don't know why....

```
class Test {
  static Test1 () { console.log(this); this.Test2();  }
  static Test2 () { console.log('qwe'); }
}

Test.Test1();

export default Test;
export const Test1 = Test.Test1;
```

This is not working!

```
class Test {
  static Test1 () { console.log(this); this.Test2();  }
  static Test2 () { console.log('qwe'); }
}

Test.Test1();

export default Test;
```

This is working!

For some reason the culprit is `export const Test1 = Test.Test1;`.